# Retrofit: Uploading file image within a model

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

Given I have these:

```
public Class Attachment{
   public String id;
   public File imageFile;
}

// Service
@Multipart
@POST("attachments")
Call<Void> upload(@Part("attachment") Attachment attachment);
```

How can I successfully upload the image file? I know there is the other technique of using `@Part MultipartBody.Part file` but I want a better approach so I can submit the data in this format:

```
attachment: {
   id: 1
   imageFile: //image data here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to upload file using java Model class but unfortunately retrofit doesn't support that.

I guess you can only send RequestBody file alone not with other values.
More over if passing id is necessary then you can pass it in header.

Here is how my file upload request looks like

```
postUserImage(@Header("accept-version") String api_version ,@Header("file_id") String file_id, @Part("image\"; filename=\"image.jpg ") RequestBody image);
```